# Spring MVC: Form Bind: Erroneous inputs do not retain value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using standard spring mvc tags, ala:

```
<form:input id="startDate" path="startDate" cssClass="datepicker" cssErrorClass="error datepicker" placeholder="Start Date" />
```

backed by a form object.

My inputs are validated on the serverside, either using annotation based binding on the form object, ala:

```
@NotNull
getStartDate() { 
    return this.startDate();
}
```

or being explicitly rejected, ala:

```
FieldError fieldErr = new FieldError("theForm", "startDate", "Please check your dates");
BindingResult result.addError(fieldErr);
```

If an input fails validation, the spring tag correctly adds the cssErrorClass to the input. However, my problem. I'd like the erroneous content to stay populated in the input tag. If 1/1/14 is determined to be invalid, I want the form to be repopulated with 1/1/14 as the value of that input.

So... help? Anyone have a workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: Simply add the validated instance to the model again.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options:
1- add the form to model again with same name used in 
2- put your form as @SeeeionAttribute, but in this case your form will be stored in session and you will need to clean your session from it after finish of using it.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work- I readd the form to the view (and I have verified that the form contains the correct data- printed it out separately), but the "<form:input" tag does not bind the form value into the created "<input" tag. 

The data is getting to the view, the form:input tag just isn't using it in cases of there being an error on that element. If there is no error, it binds correctly.

Comment: did you try 2 ways ? can you check if get method run again before showing error or not ?